# Randomize one column values based on multiple other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, random

I have the following df:

```
structure(list(Donorcode = c("406A001", "406A002", "406A003", 
"406A004"), Doos = c(1, 1, 2, 2), `Leeftijd T0` = c(70, 73, 79, 
75), Instituut = c("Spaarne ziekenhuis", "Spaarne ziekenhuis", 
"Spaarne ziekenhuis", "Spaarne ziekenhuis"), Datum = structure(c(1567468800, 
1567468800, 1567468800, 1567468800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I need to randomize the column 'Donorcode' based on the other 4 columns, not one column 'weighs' more than the other so the order of which column randomizes the Donorcode column first does not matter.

Is there a way to do this in R?

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you meant something like `df$Donorcode <- df$Donorcode[rank(do.call(paste, df[-1]))]`

Comment: Unfortunately no, i changed all columns except df$Donorcode to a factor now and what I need is that there is an equal amount of each level when randomizing